# How to non-interactively squash a git branch with a long history (before merge)?

Tags: git, pull-request

A little bit of background.

My company has a large git repository. We do development on a branch (hopefully short-living) and then perform a merge (without squash) to the master. Unfortunately, now we have a project that lived on its own branch for months. Multiple developers contributed to it, and it has well over one hundred commits. Few dozen of those commits are merges from master, and they are interlaced with our own commits.

Now we want to merge all of this code to the master - but in a form of all little commits. We want to squash them. However, we face an opposition from DevOps. Merges are done automatically by a tool, and DevOps insist that git "squash and merge" operation can lead to problems. In short, they won't do any squashes or rebases for us. We are perfectly fine with losing all of our individual commit history. But any possibility of messing up the master (or introducing erroneous merges) should be eliminated.

**How can we automatically squash the commits on a pull request BEFORE making a merge?**

I know we can do "git rebase", but this would be a manual process of going through all 100+ commits. Error-prone. Not good enough for us.

When running "git diff" I can see all the changes between our branch and the master, nice and clean. Is there a way to:

1. Transform all of those changes into ONE commit;
2. Do it automatically (no need for human input during the process);
3. With rewriting branch history (should end up with master rebasing + 1 big commit instead of 100s of small commits);
4. All done on the branch before (not during) the merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a single commit that has all the differences from master as a single commit, you can do this:

```
git checkout the-branch
git merge master -m "get the latest from master"
# set our branch _pointer_ on master, do not change a comma from our working tree
git reset --soft master
# at this point, all the differences between master and the other branch are on index, ready to be committed
git commit -m "single commit with all changes"
```

And you are done. Your branch is a single commit on top of master, no hassle.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. One more thing, to finish it off, I need to use "git push --force"

Comment: To push to your remote branch? Yes

Comment: Yes, to push to the remote branch. The ultimate goal is a merge to the parent (master) branch with the lowest number of commits.